# AJAX working on Desktop but not Mobile Jquery Mobile

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile app I'm making and I have a right side panel that is to display "notifications" for the user.  When I login and see it on the desktop browser (chrome and firefox) I can see to notifications no problem, but when I look at it on my mobile browser (chrome and safari) the notifications do no appear.  I'm using Ajax to call the notifications.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).toggle();
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#myContent").load("getnotes.php?name=<? echo $username; ?>");
    });
}
</script>

<!-- BEGIN PAGE 1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="feed" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="panel" id="settingspanel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay">
<!--LEFT SIDE PANEL CONTENT HERE-->

    </div>

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c" data-tap-toggle="false" data-id="foo1" style="padding-top: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #eccfb3; padding-bottom: 5px;">
        <a href="#settingspanel" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" class="icon-reorder icon-2x" style="background: none; margin-left: 20px;"></a>
        <center><img src="images/logo_app_white.png" height="25px"></center>

    <!--THIS IS THE BUTTON TO PUSH TO MAKE NOTIFICATIONS APPEAR-->  
        <a href="#myContent" data-ajax="false" onclick="toggleDiv('myContent');" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" class="icon-bell-alt icon-2x" style="background: none; margin-right: 20px;"></a><? echo $number; ?>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   

        <!--THIS IS WHERE CONTENT FOR THE PAGE GOES-->


    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c" data-tap-toggle="false" data-id="foo1" style="border-top: 1px solid #eccfb3; padding-top: 5px;">
        <div data-role="navbar" style="background: #ce8339;">
                <!--ICONS FOR NAVIGATION BAR-->
        </div><!-- /navbar -->  
    </div>

        <!--HERE IS WHERE THE NOTIFICATIONS APPEAR-->
    <div data-role="panel" id="myContent" data-position="right" data-display="overlay">


    </div>


</div>

<!-- END PAGE 1 -->
```

Why is it working on the desktop but not the mobile?

Comment: What version of jQuery Mobile is compatible with 1.4.4? jQM 1.0.1 required jquery 1.6.4

Comment: I've used <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> with it before.

Comment: this is what I have now:

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>

Comment: EVen with the 1.8.3 jquery i'm having the same issue

Comment: Figure out the "why" it is not working by switching to $.ajax and adding an error handler.

Comment: I'm new to ajax so could you help me place the code to get an error handler?

Comment: `$.ajax({url: "page.php",success: function(html){alert(html)},error: function(xhr,status,error){ alert(status);alert(error); }})`